# Output of python scripts displayed only at termination when using SSH?

Tags: python, ssh, stdout

I'm running a script to manage processes on a remote (SSH) machine. Let's call it **five.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time, subprocess

subprocess.call('echo 0',shell=True)
for i in range(1,5):
   time.sleep(1)
   print(i)
```

If i now run

```
ssh user@host five.py
```

I would like to see the output

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

appear on my standard out second by second (as it does if execute locally).. What happens is: I get the 0 from "echo" right away and the rest only appears at once after the entire program finishes. (Doesn't help to nest 'five.py' into a bash script; to call it by 'python five.py'; or to use 'print >> sys.stdout, i').

This must be related to the way python writes to stdout, since other programs behave quite normal.. A functional workaround is

```
import time, subprocess
import sys

subprocess.call('echo 0',shell=True)
for i in range(1,5):
  time.sleep(1)
  sys.stdout.write(str(i)+'\n')
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

But there must be a better solution than changing all my print statements!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the -u on the shebang line as interjay hinted

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
```

You could also reopen stdout with buffering turned off or set to line buffering

```
import os,sys
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0) # no buffering
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 1) # line buffering
```

Usually line buffering is a good choice

Comment: Thanks a lot: 'sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 1)' works very well and should be more secure than 'python -u'

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `sys.stdout` object so that it automatically flushes after each write. This will also affect the `print` statement. An example, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print/288536#288536):

```
class flushfile(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def write(self, x):
        self.f.write(x)
        self.f.flush()

import sys
sys.stdout = flushfile(sys.stdout)
```

---

Edit: Another option is to start Python with the [`-u`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) option, which will force input and output to be unbuffered.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might look at using since you are already using Python is [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/), much nicer way to do remote SSH work. Here is an [article](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2010/02/python-remote-ssh-with-paramiko/) about how I am using it in its most basic form.